# Set default media files in Docker using Django

Tags: django, docker, nginx, django-models, docker-compose

I am deploying my Django web application using Docker and Docker Compose, Nginx and Postgresql. I have already done the deployment and it works well. But I have **a problem with the default media files**.

When I was deploying in local and in my server, I add those default media files manually to the media folder, but now with Docker I can't do that.

**One of my models would be that one, which has a default image *"dictionary/default.png"*** and obviously when I run my docker image doesn't load because it doesn't exist anywhere.

```
class Dictionary(models.Model):

      dictionary_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      dictionary_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='dictionary', default='dictionary/default.png')
```

I was thinking to have these default media files locally and copy them to the Docker media folder in the Dockerfile, but I do not know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) instruction in the Dockerfile.

For example, copy all files from the `dictionary` to the `media`:

```
...
COPY dictionary/ /app/media/
...
```

If you already set `WORKDIR /app`:

```
...
COPY dictionary/ ./media/
...
```